# Limit of sum of two nonnegative functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be well-defined continous nonnegative functions. Moreover, let $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)+g(x)=0$. Can I conclude that the limits $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$,$\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ exsist and are zero?

Idea: Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)+g(x)=0$ there must be a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)+g(x)<\epsilon$ for all $x>\delta$. Now assume that one of the limits doesn't exsist or is not zero (let's say the limit for $g$). Then there is a $x>\delta$ such that $g(x)>\epsilon$. But since $f,g$ are nonnegative this gives $f(x)+g(x)>\epsilon$, which is a contradiction.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It follows from $0 \le f(x) \le f(x)+g(x)$.

Comment: Perhaps you need to understand that this is at the same level as the obvious fact "if the sum of two positive numbers is small then the individual numbers are even smaller".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Now assume that one of the limits doesn't exist or is not zero (let's say the limit for g). Then there is a $x\gt\delta$ such that $g(x)\gt\epsilon$" **this statement is false.**

The correct one is If we assume $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x)\neq0$, then there is $\epsilon_0\gt0$ s.t for all $\delta\gt0$ there is $x_\delta\gt\delta$ s.t $g(x_\delta)\geq\epsilon_0$.

So the contradiction would be, for that $\epsilon_0$ you cannot find a $\delta$ s.t $f(x)+g(x)\lt\epsilon_0$ for all $x\gt\delta$ since what ever $\delta$ you choose $f(x_\delta)+g(x_\delta)\geq\epsilon_0$.

Comment: Yes, thank you!